# Automatic transaction

Tags: transactions, security

I would like to know if it was possible to automatically send any ETH amout to an address "B" just after receiving them on an address "A"? Maybe via a script? I need help

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck! Ethereum's smart contracts can do just the thing!

Check out this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Forward {
    address public receiver;

    // Constructor, pass the address of the account you want this contract
    // to forward any incoming ether to.
    function Forward(address _receiver) {
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

    function() public payable {
        // Forward the received ether to receiver, as well as some gas,
        // which the receiver can use to run code
        // If something goes wrong, the ether is sent back
        require(receiver.call.gas(gasleft() - 2000).value(msg.value)());
    }
}
```

This smart contract will send any received ether to `receiver`.

Now, to use this contract, you will have to deploy it. To do that, take a look at the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/index.html).

Also: please only use this contract on the testnet, unless you are sure you know what you are doing. It's real money we're dealing with here.

If you want to create smart contracts for yourself, you can use [Remix IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org) to write and test them!

Comment: thank you very much for this quick answer, I will indeed try on the testnet.

Comment: I tried the contract forwarder, but this is not working. Send ETH to the ETH address, it just sends the ETH. No forwarding.
Send ETH to the contract address, out of gas. Do we need to put in an address somewhere in the solidity code?

Comment: Oh yeah the fallback function is ideal. You could use another payable function if you wanted too